# Java: nextInt() validation doesn't work property

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm not Java expert and I have a problem. I'm getting data from the keyboard using Scanner, but I have to do 2 validations before registering the data to my array. One is, the data doesn't have to be a string and I'm using `!in.hastNextInt()` to validate wherein the Scanner instance, and the other one is that the data doesn't have to be `0`. and the code I'm using is the next one:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int chain [] = new int [10];

    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter the values for the array: ");
    for(int x = 0;x < chain.length; x++) {
       System.out.print((x+1) +": ");
       while(!in.hasNextInt() || in.nextInt()==0) {
           System.out.print("This app doesn't accept letters, symbols or zeros: ");
           in.next();
       }
       chain[x] = in.nextInt();
    }
```

and unfortunately, when I run the program it asks me twice per each statement, for example, asks me twice per position 0 of the array and twice per position 1 of the array.

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?
It works perfectly with `!in.hasNextInt()` but when im using `in.nextInt()==0` gives me that problem or when I use only `in.nextInt()==0` alone

what is my error and what do you recommend me to change in my code to make it work well.
I appreciate any help

Thank you in advance

**as @Andreas told in his answer I had to change my code and the new good one is:**

```
for(int x = 0;x < chain; x++) {
   System.out.print((x+1) +": ");
   while(!in.hasNextInt()) {
       System.out.print("This app doesn't accept letters or symbols: ");
       in.next();
   }
   chain[x] = in.nextInt();
   if(chain[x] == 0)    {
       System.out.println("This app doesn't accept 0");
       --x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextInt()` *consumes* the token, so when you do `in.nextInt()==0`, you read a token and loop if the value is zero.

If the token is not zero, the loop ends and you execute `chain[x] = in.nextInt()`, which reads the *next* token. Not the same token again.

You should capture the value in a variable, then check for zero, and use it if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I have an idea but at this moment im at public transport. I will try what you say in a few hours and tell you if works. :)

Comment: Thanks for help, I changed my code and it works. Thank you so much. You can see the new one in answer